# Induction proof $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{2} = \frac{1}{6} n(n+1)(2n+1)$

Tags: induction

I'm asked to prove $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{2} = \frac{1}{6} n(n+1)(2n+1)$$ 
using proof by induction.

Now, I know how to do induction proofs and I end up at this step, needing to prove that:

$$\frac{1}{6} n(n+1)(2n+1) + (n+1)^2 = \frac{1}{6} (n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)$$

So $$n(2n+1) + n+1 = (n+2)(2n+3)$$
$$2n^2 + 2n + 1 = 2n^2 + 7n + 6$$

which is obviously not equal.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3):

Dividing by $(n+1)$ was good, but when you got rid of the $\frac16$ factor, you forgot to multiply the $(n+1)^2$ term by $6$.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the $(n+1)^2$ term on the left does not have a factor of $\frac16$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple visual proof of this: [link](https://fr0ddy.github.io/math/visual-proofs/sum-of-first-n-squares.html)

[image]